# html table frozen columns with pure javascript, little CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable, html-table

I'm trying to implement making the left three columns of an html horizontally scrolling table 'frozen' or 'fixed'. I've already looked thoroughly at all of the solutions on the web but I have a lot of requirements which make it impossible to find a solution:

1. Make as little CSS changes as possible as this table already has a lot of CSS applied to it. This table has a lot of the same features as [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) so there's a lot going on.
2. I'm willing to do as much Javascript as needed but it needs to be purely JS, nothing else like jQuery.
3. Cannot duplicate the table (I've seen solutions that puts one copy of the table on top of another).
4. The table must stay completely white, I cannot assign a background color to the frozen columns as a 'fix' to hide the other columns when frozen column scrolls over them.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to implement that functionality with Javascript? It seems like most implementations that apply to an existing table (and not include this feature in a table) depend on changing a lot of CSS. Even just some suggestions on how to get started with it in javascript would be helpful. I would think that there should be a way if I utilize the scrolling aspect, but I'm not sure.

Comment: can have html files?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a fixed-table.js library to implement the solution without jquery. Try the snippet below.

```js
var fixedTable = fixTable(document.getElementById('fixed-table-container-demo'));

function fixTable(container) {
  // Store references to table elements
  var thead = container.querySelector('thead');
  var tbody = container.querySelector('tbody');

  // Style container
  container.style.overflow = 'auto';
  container.style.position = 'relative';

  // Add inline styles to fix the header row and leftmost column
  function relayout() {
    var ths = [].slice.call(thead.querySelectorAll('th'));
    var tbodyTrs = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr'));

    /**
     * Remove inline styles so we resort to the default table layout algorithm
     * For thead, th, and td elements, don't remove the 'transform' styles applied
     * by the scroll event listener
     */
    tbody.setAttribute('style', '');
    thead.style.width = '';
    thead.style.position = '';
    thead.style.top = '';
    thead.style.left = '';
    thead.style.zIndex = '';
    ths.forEach(function(th) {
      th.style.display = '';
      th.style.width = '';
      th.style.position = '';
      th.style.top = '';
      th.style.left = '';
    });
    tbodyTrs.forEach(function(tr) {
      tr.setAttribute('style', '');
    });
    [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll('td'))
      .forEach(function(td) {
        td.style.width = '';
        td.style.position = '';
        td.style.left = '';
      });

    /**
     * Store width and height of each th
     * getBoundingClientRect()'s dimensions include paddings and borders
     */
    var thStyles = ths.map(function(th) {
      var rect = th.getBoundingClientRect();
      var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(th, '');
      return {
        boundingWidth: rect.width,
        boundingHeight: rect.height,
        width: parseInt(style.width, 10),
        paddingLeft: parseInt(style.paddingLeft, 10)
      };
    });

    // Set widths of thead and tbody
    var totalWidth = thStyles.reduce(function(sum, cur) {
      return sum + cur.boundingWidth;
    }, 0);
    tbody.style.display = 'block';
    tbody.style.width = totalWidth + 'px';
    thead.style.width = totalWidth - thStyles[0].boundingWidth + 'px';

    // Position thead
    thead.style.position = 'absolute';
    thead.style.top = '0';
    thead.style.left = thStyles[0].boundingWidth + 'px';
    thead.style.zIndex = 10;

    // Set widths of the th elements in thead. For the fixed th, set its position
    ths.forEach(function(th, i) {
      th.style.width = thStyles[i].width + 'px';
      if (i === 0) {
        th.style.position = 'absolute';
        th.style.top = '0';
        th.style.left = -thStyles[0].boundingWidth + 'px';
      }
    });

    // Set margin-top for tbody - the fixed header is displayed in this margin
    tbody.style.marginTop = thStyles[0].boundingHeight + 'px';

    // Set widths of the td elements in tbody. For the fixed td, set its position
    tbodyTrs.forEach(function(tr, i) {
      tr.style.display = 'block';
      tr.style.paddingLeft = thStyles[0].boundingWidth + 'px';
      [].slice.call(tr.querySelectorAll('td'))
        .forEach(function(td, j) {
          td.style.width = thStyles[j].width + 'px';
          if (j === 0) {
            td.style.position = 'absolute';
            td.style.left = '0';
          }
        });
    });
  }

  // Initialize table styles
  relayout();

  // Update table cell dimensions on resize
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeThrottler, false);
  var resizeTimeout;

  function resizeThrottler() {
    if (!resizeTimeout) {
      resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeTimeout = null;
        relayout();
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  // Fix thead and first column on scroll
  container.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    thead.style.transform = 'translate3d(0,' + this.scrollTop + 'px,0)';
    var hTransform = 'translate3d(' + this.scrollLeft + 'px,0,0)';
    thead.querySelector('th').style.transform = hTransform;
    [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr > td:first-child'))
      .forEach(function(td, i) {
        td.style.transform = hTransform;
      });
  });

  /**
   * Return an object that exposes the relayout function so that we can
   * update the table when the number of columns or the content inside columns changes
   */
  return {
    relayout: relayout
  };
}
```

```css
.fixed-table-container {
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.fixed-table-container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed-table-container th,
.fixed-table-container td {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  /**
    * Current implementation doesn't work when
    * cells in a row have different heights
    */
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}

.fixed-table-container th {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.fixed-table-container td:first-child {
  background: #fff;
}

.fixed-table-container tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.fixed-table-container th:last-child,
.fixed-table-container td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed-table-container-demo" class="fixed-table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Dolor</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        <td>sit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Sit amet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Dolor</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        <td>sit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem dolor sit amet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</td>
        <td>Sit amet lorem</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Is there a way to implement this feature (at least the frozen column part) by not having to give the frozen column a colored background (cell is white but you still do not see the other columns when scrolling over)?

Comment: you want whole table to be white background is it?

Comment: Correct. Right now the solution only works because the gray background of the frozen column hides the other data, but how to hide the data without using a background color?

Comment: check now, i changed the color

Comment: That makes sense. How do you implement this for more than one frozen column though? Like 2 columns?